# Swift login functionality using Active Directory Credentials/authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I need to create a login mechanism in an IOS App.
The app is created using the Swift language. 
The app needs to call a Windows Server, with the credentials provided by the user. And afterwards hold the "logged in" state until user is removed from active directory or the user logs out manually.

I have been looking through documentation, but can't seem to find anything on the specific topic.
How can I move on to solve the above problem?
I did find some existing code based on Objective C, but not sure how to implement this, any guide, tutorial or explanation is welcomed.

Comment: Is the app consuming web services (such as REST) from the Windows server or do you just want to use the authentication for "local" access to the app?

Comment: It's the intention to use it for authentication purposes only. And now when i see your comment i wonder why you say local. it might not be possible to have remote access, unless it's on VPN. ?

Comment: I was wondering if you wanted the AD authentication to control access to the app itself or if it was to authenticate against some web service - if the latter then you should be able to perform the authentication through the web server and the app won't need to do anything special - just provide a username/password

Comment: Oh. I want the AD authentication to control access to the content in the app. So users should be presented with a login screen as initial screen. I want the app to authenticate against a windows server (AD). And afterwards keep credentials in app for future use.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: At its simplest it is just an LDAP bind against an AD server - if it succeeds then the user is authenticated if not, then not.  You can store the username/password in the keychain and retry next time the app is started.  If it fails then ask the user for their username/password again (password may have been changed for example). You won't know that the user as been removed/deactivated in AD until you retry the authentication and get a fail